# No CANbus response to broadcast

Tags: can, obd

I am trying to create a simple OBD tool in Linux to talk to my car (2009 Honda Accord).  My OBD device successfully connects and I see lots of CAN frames arrive.  However, when I issue an OBD command (I've tried a few) I don't get any response.

I have setup my device as follow:

```
link set can0 type can bitrate 500000
```

and I confirmed the status as follows:

```
2: can0: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 10
    link/can  promiscuity 0 minmtu 0 maxmtu 0 
    can state ERROR-ACTIVE (berr-counter tx 0 rx 0) restart-ms 0 
          bitrate 500000 sample-point 0.875 
          tq 12 prop-seg 69 phase-seg1 70 phase-seg2 20 sjw 1
          pcan_usb_fd: tseg1 1..256 tseg2 1..128 sjw 1..128 brp 1..1024 brp-inc 1
          pcan_usb_fd: dtseg1 1..32 dtseg2 1..16 dsjw 1..16 dbrp 1..1024 dbrp-inc 1
          clock 80000000 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535
```

In one terminal window I send a simple CAN command (vehicle information / service 09, show supported PID's / PID 00):

```
cansend can0 7DF#0209000000000000
```

In anotherterminal window I dump any CAN frames with ID 780 or greater, and I can see the command I just issued appear:

```
candump can0,780:780
  can0  7DF   [8]  02 09 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

But that's it..no OBD responses.  Why?  Given the year of the vehicle I'm sure it supports OBD (by law it has to).  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Even if it has OBD, is it supported over CAN or some other interface? Also you may need to figure out a correct sequence when to plug in and when to start communicating, and in which ignition key states these must happen. So you might not have an electrical engineering question after all. It might be how to use your device in Linux question, or how to connect with OBD to a car question.

Comment: OBD are a collection of different protocols. It doesn't have to be CAN 500 kbps.

Comment: According to [this](https://pinoutguide.com/CarElectronics/honda_obd_2_pinout.shtml), it seems like your Honda Accord supports ISO 9141-2  (K/L Line) instead of CAN.

Comment: @Velvel I see that the connector has CAN and KLINE pins.  (I know little about kline).  Does that mean if a vehicle has KLINE then all OBD communications must be on the KLINE pins?  Or will ECU's still respond to OBD queries on the CANbus?

Comment: I'm not sure about mixed communication lines. I would recommend you get this [SparkFun OBD-II UART](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9555) interface. It supports all OBD2 protocols over a UART interface.

Answer (score 1):

As noted (by Velvel) in a comment above, this vehicle uses K-Line bus for OBD communications, and CAN bus (F-CAN) for CAN communications from the OBD port.

For anyone else facing the same, try AutoCommander (https://autocommander.io) under linux to talk to capture what you need.  It supports multiple simultaneous bus interfaces, so you can capture both the initial command and all responses.  If you are trying to switch a single OBD adapter from send to monitor mode then the time to do so will be too long (the response will arrive before your OBD adapter has even switched), which may be why you dont see a response.  In case your vehicle uses one bus for diagnostics and another (or multiple CAN busses) you may have to sniff multiple busses at once.  Sending a diagnostic command on K-Line may result in frames appearing on the CAN bus.

This is a *free* tool, available from the Telium website.  I'm one of the dev's and I've used this to capture and find frames on a range of vehicles.  Note that you should be using multiple adapters (eg :ELM327 or obdsol) to do this kind of work.  So 2 K-Line compatible adapters with a Y adapter on the OBD port.  We built this tool precisely because of the problem explained in the original question - we couldn't capture what we needed from the single adapter.

Comment: TSG - Hi, Since you are linking to (and therefore effectively promoting) "AutoCommander" which is a product of the company you are associated with, you **must** disclose that affiliation in your post (see [this](/help/promotion) site rule). Failure to do so could see your account being treated as a spammer. Please edit your post to comply with that site rule immediately. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson - Although full disclosure is in the account info, I've added more to the question as well. This "product" is a free tool, not promoting a commercial interest which is spam. The link you offered refers to "something you are selling" which is not the case. The answer post offers the only way a user is going to solve this type of problem. We built a tool to monitor monitor multiple busses at once, or at least a single bus with multiple adapters.

Comment: TSG - "*Although full disclosure is in the account info*" I respectfully disagree - AutoCommander is not in your profile. And disclosure *must* be in the post itself, not just in the profile anyway. As a moderator I am *very* familiar with these rules and how they are applied. Re: "*free tool*" It also doesn't matter that the tool is (currently) free - you are linking to something you are affiliated with, so disclosure is required. (Actually disclosure is required just for linking to an associated *website*, irrespective of the price of the tool.) || Thanks for adding a disclosure to the post.